# SyntaxError: invalid syntax python, what's the cause?

Tags: python, file, import, syntax-error

I tried this

```
for i in range(len(current_pos)):
  vector.append(to_pos[i] - current_pos[i])

distance = math.sqrt((vector[0]2)+(vector[1]2))
angle = math.degrees(math.atan(vector[1]/vector[0]))

print(vector[1], vector[0])
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What is the cause of this syntax error? Now I just write because I need more details.

Comment: Why are you calling `vector[0]2`? Care to explain - What is `vector`? Is it A list or a list of lists  ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

```
vector[0]2
```

What should above code do?

---

Do you want this?

```
guettli@yoga15:~$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> 2**4

16
```

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: just to say, RTFineManual about base Python syntax?

Comment: what? y did u wrote 2**4?

Answer (score 0):

The power operation is done with **. So modify your code as

```
for i in range(len(current_pos)):
  vector.append(to_pos[i] - current_pos[i])

distance = math.sqrt((vector[0]**2)+(vector[1]**2))
angle = math.degrees(math.atan(vector[1]/vector[0]))

print(vector[1], vector[0])
```